# How am I able to to assign Json values (a few different data types) to variables to be able to use them in a Java Application?

Tags: java, json

I am completely new to JSON and the file I'm dealing with has lots of objects inside objects (and they're all different variable types e.g. String, Int, Boolean). I am trying to create a weather prediction program. I have tried converting it to a csv and trying to take the values out of the JSON array but unfortunately I am having troubles with all the different variable types. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted the JSON content below:

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0029,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [{
    "dt": 1517173200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.57,
        "temp_min": 282.104,
        "temp_max": 282.57,
        "pressure": 1033.47,
        "sea_level": 1043.6,
        "grnd_level": 1033.47,
        "humidity": 88,
        "temp_kf": 0.47
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 64
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.12,
        "deg": 246.005
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.015
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-28 21:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517184000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.21,
        "temp_min": 281.86,
        "temp_max": 282.21,
        "pressure": 1032.19,
        "sea_level": 1042.34,
        "grnd_level": 1032.19,
        "humidity": 89,
        "temp_kf": 0.35
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 88
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.31,
        "deg": 246.502
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.065
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 00:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517194800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.23,
        "temp_min": 281.993,
        "temp_max": 282.23,
        "pressure": 1030.92,
        "sea_level": 1041.15,
        "grnd_level": 1030.92,
        "humidity": 88,
        "temp_kf": 0.24
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 76
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.05,
        "deg": 248.007
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.1
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 03:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517205600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.83,
        "temp_min": 282.712,
        "temp_max": 282.83,
        "pressure": 1029.66,
        "sea_level": 1039.73,
        "grnd_level": 1029.66,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0.12
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.23,
        "deg": 249.501
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.13
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 06:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517216400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 283.386,
        "temp_min": 283.386,
        "temp_max": 283.386,
        "pressure": 1028.77,
        "sea_level": 1038.91,
        "grnd_level": 1028.77,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.1,
        "deg": 250.003
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.15
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 09:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517227200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 284.502,
        "temp_min": 284.502,
        "temp_max": 284.502,
        "pressure": 1027.71,
        "sea_level": 1037.77,
        "grnd_level": 1027.71,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.17,
        "deg": 248.004
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.57
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 12:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517238000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.125,
        "temp_min": 282.125,
        "temp_max": 282.125,
        "pressure": 1029.47,
        "sea_level": 1039.55,
        "grnd_level": 1029.47,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.21,
        "deg": 323.003
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 1.865
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 15:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517248800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 278.662,
        "temp_min": 278.662,
        "temp_max": 278.662,
        "pressure": 1032.69,
        "sea_level": 1042.99,
        "grnd_level": 1032.69,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.47,
        "deg": 314.005
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 18:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517259600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 276.508,
        "temp_min": 276.508,
        "temp_max": 276.508,
        "pressure": 1035.09,
        "sea_level": 1045.44,
        "grnd_level": 1035.09,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.42,
        "deg": 293.004
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-29 21:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517270400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 274.987,
        "temp_min": 274.987,
        "temp_max": 274.987,
        "pressure": 1035.85,
        "sea_level": 1046.28,
        "grnd_level": 1035.85,
        "humidity": 93,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.23,
        "deg": 285.002
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 00:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517281200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 273.6,
        "temp_min": 273.6,
        "temp_max": 273.6,
        "pressure": 1035.63,
        "sea_level": 1046.13,
        "grnd_level": 1035.63,
        "humidity": 89,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.07,
        "deg": 250.502
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 03:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517292000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 273.127,
        "temp_min": 273.127,
        "temp_max": 273.127,
        "pressure": 1035.12,
        "sea_level": 1045.78,
        "grnd_level": 1035.12,
        "humidity": 90,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.73,
        "deg": 244.001
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 06:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517302800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 273.276,
        "temp_min": 273.276,
        "temp_max": 273.276,
        "pressure": 1034.91,
        "sea_level": 1045.49,
        "grnd_level": 1034.91,
        "humidity": 86,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "02d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 8
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.73,
        "deg": 206.501
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 09:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517313600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.265,
        "temp_min": 279.265,
        "temp_max": 279.265,
        "pressure": 1033.09,
        "sea_level": 1043.32,
        "grnd_level": 1033.09,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.59,
        "deg": 207.001
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 12:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517324400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.913,
        "temp_min": 279.913,
        "temp_max": 279.913,
        "pressure": 1029.52,
        "sea_level": 1039.73,
        "grnd_level": 1029.52,
        "humidity": 90,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.32,
        "deg": 213.507
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 15:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517335200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.804,
        "temp_min": 277.804,
        "temp_max": 277.804,
        "pressure": 1026.44,
        "sea_level": 1036.74,
        "grnd_level": 1026.44,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 44
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.85,
        "deg": 199.001
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 18:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517346000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 278.566,
        "temp_min": 278.566,
        "temp_max": 278.566,
        "pressure": 1021.17,
        "sea_level": 1031.32,
        "grnd_level": 1021.17,
        "humidity": 96,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.36,
        "deg": 191.003
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.66
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-30 21:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517356800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 282.617,
        "temp_min": 282.617,
        "temp_max": 282.617,
        "pressure": 1016,
        "sea_level": 1026.08,
        "grnd_level": 1016,
        "humidity": 95,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.51,
        "deg": 237.501
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 2.06
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 00:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517367600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 281.237,
        "temp_min": 281.237,
        "temp_max": 281.237,
        "pressure": 1013.75,
        "sea_level": 1023.88,
        "grnd_level": 1013.75,
        "humidity": 96,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.06,
        "deg": 256.001
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.62
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 03:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517378400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 281.267,
        "temp_min": 281.267,
        "temp_max": 281.267,
        "pressure": 1011.51,
        "sea_level": 1021.54,
        "grnd_level": 1011.51,
        "humidity": 95,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 88
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.33,
        "deg": 257.505
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.5
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 06:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517389200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.674,
        "temp_min": 279.674,
        "temp_max": 279.674,
        "pressure": 1011.09,
        "sea_level": 1021.14,
        "grnd_level": 1011.09,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 24
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.3,
        "deg": 263.503
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.04
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 09:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517400000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.173,
        "temp_min": 279.173,
        "temp_max": 279.173,
        "pressure": 1010.11,
        "sea_level": 1020.08,
        "grnd_level": 1010.11,
        "humidity": 96,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 80
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.26,
        "deg": 272.001
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 1.34
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 12:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517410800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.275,
        "temp_min": 279.275,
        "temp_max": 279.275,
        "pressure": 1008.09,
        "sea_level": 1018.11,
        "grnd_level": 1008.09,
        "humidity": 94,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 48
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.01,
        "deg": 270
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 15:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517421600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.443,
        "temp_min": 277.443,
        "temp_max": 277.443,
        "pressure": 1006.4,
        "sea_level": 1016.46,
        "grnd_level": 1006.4,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.01,
        "deg": 264.501
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 18:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517432400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.065,
        "temp_min": 277.065,
        "temp_max": 277.065,
        "pressure": 1004.03,
        "sea_level": 1014.1,
        "grnd_level": 1004.03,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 802,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "scattered clouds",
        "icon": "03n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 32
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.98,
        "deg": 251.501
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-01-31 21:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517443200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.557,
        "temp_min": 277.557,
        "temp_max": 277.557,
        "pressure": 1001.39,
        "sea_level": 1011.39,
        "grnd_level": 1001.39,
        "humidity": 86,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 64
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.96,
        "deg": 258.501
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.02
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 00:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517454000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.952,
        "temp_min": 277.952,
        "temp_max": 277.952,
        "pressure": 997.38,
        "sea_level": 1007.44,
        "grnd_level": 997.38,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 68
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.4,
        "deg": 253.001
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.02
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 03:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517464800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.626,
        "temp_min": 277.626,
        "temp_max": 277.626,
        "pressure": 994.99,
        "sea_level": 1005.22,
        "grnd_level": 994.99,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.16,
        "deg": 290.5
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.54
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 06:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517475600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 276.999,
        "temp_min": 276.999,
        "temp_max": 276.999,
        "pressure": 1000.97,
        "sea_level": 1011.14,
        "grnd_level": 1000.97,
        "humidity": 95,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 11.51,
        "deg": 357.005
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 1.51
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 09:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517486400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.994,
        "temp_min": 277.994,
        "temp_max": 277.994,
        "pressure": 1006.61,
        "sea_level": 1016.71,
        "grnd_level": 1006.61,
        "humidity": 93,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 36
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 9.61,
        "deg": 344.501
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.059999999999999
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 12:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517497200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 278.503,
        "temp_min": 278.503,
        "temp_max": 278.503,
        "pressure": 1008.13,
        "sea_level": 1018.32,
        "grnd_level": 1008.13,
        "humidity": 86,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 76
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.56,
        "deg": 335.5
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.0099999999999998
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 15:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517508000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 278.147,
        "temp_min": 278.147,
        "temp_max": 278.147,
        "pressure": 1011.25,
        "sea_level": 1021.29,
        "grnd_level": 1011.25,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 56
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.51,
        "deg": 356.505
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.22
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 18:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517518800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.529,
        "temp_min": 277.529,
        "temp_max": 277.529,
        "pressure": 1014.07,
        "sea_level": 1024.28,
        "grnd_level": 1014.07,
        "humidity": 87,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 92
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.26,
        "deg": 350.501
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.23
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-01 21:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517529600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.027,
        "temp_min": 277.027,
        "temp_max": 277.027,
        "pressure": 1016.85,
        "sea_level": 1027.01,
        "grnd_level": 1016.85,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.16,
        "deg": 0.00292969
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.07
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 00:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517540400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 275.98,
        "temp_min": 275.98,
        "temp_max": 275.98,
        "pressure": 1019.25,
        "sea_level": 1029.5,
        "grnd_level": 1019.25,
        "humidity": 83,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 12
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.55,
        "deg": 1.5011
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 03:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517551200,
    "main": {
        "temp": 275.064,
        "temp_min": 275.064,
        "temp_max": 275.064,
        "pressure": 1021.34,
        "sea_level": 1031.64,
        "grnd_level": 1021.34,
        "humidity": 84,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "02n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 8
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 5.11,
        "deg": 1.00006
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 06:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517562000,
    "main": {
        "temp": 274.354,
        "temp_min": 274.354,
        "temp_max": 274.354,
        "pressure": 1023.32,
        "sea_level": 1033.73,
        "grnd_level": 1023.32,
        "humidity": 91,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.76,
        "deg": 355.502
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 09:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517572800,
    "main": {
        "temp": 278.331,
        "temp_min": 278.331,
        "temp_max": 278.331,
        "pressure": 1024.86,
        "sea_level": 1035.07,
        "grnd_level": 1024.86,
        "humidity": 93,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "02d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 8
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.56,
        "deg": 351.002
    },
    "rain": {},
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 12:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517583600,
    "main": {
        "temp": 279.161,
        "temp_min": 279.161,
        "temp_max": 279.161,
        "pressure": 1024.46,
        "sea_level": 1034.7,
        "grnd_level": 1024.46,
        "humidity": 86,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 56
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.56,
        "deg": 338.001
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.02
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 15:00:00"
}, {
    "dt": 1517594400,
    "main": {
        "temp": 277.055,
        "temp_min": 277.055,
        "temp_max": 277.055,
        "pressure": 1025.12,
        "sea_level": 1035.4,
        "grnd_level": 1025.12,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": 0
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10n"
    }],
    "clouds": {
        "all": 44
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.66,
        "deg": 294.004
    },
    "rain": {
        "3h": 0.029999999999999
    },
    "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2018-02-02 18:00:00"
}],
"city": {
    "id": 2633709,
    "name": "Woking",
    "coord": {
        "lat": 51.319,
        "lon": -0.559
    },
    "country": "GB"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to think from object perspective. Your outer most Object is some kind of wrapper which contains most other important objects.

I have tried to convert the JSON to appropriate object structure. I hope you get my point. Please add missing objects.

```
public class OuterMainObject {
    private String cod;
    private float message;
    private int cnt;
    List<WeatherObject> list = new ArrayList<WeatherObject>();
    private City city;

}

class City {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Coordinates coord;
    private String country;
}

class Coordinates {
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
}

class WeatherObject {
    private Date dt; 
    private Main main;
    private Weather weather;
    private Clouds clouds;
    private Wind wind;
    private Rain rain;
    private Sys sys;
    private String dt_txt;

}
```

As you can see I have one `OuterMainObject` and there are multiple objects within that `outermainobject` now if you try and map the objects from outside to inside you can easily relate them.

**Update for comment**
We don't have to worry about how to detect and store the variables. There are libraries which does this for us. So for example Jackson is one of such library. Please refer to this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/). This one has a nice tutorial about this conversion. All you need to focus is converting the JSON to appropriate object structure.

In your case following should do it.

```
OuterMainObject obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, OuterMainObject.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Whilst that is helpful unfortunately I don't think I've fully explained my issue. I'm having problems getting the data from the JSON and saving it into objects. I have tried using getJSONArray("list") for example and it misses half of the array. How are you able to save the specific data to the variables in the objects?

Answer (score 0):

**try like this.....**

```
JSONObject JOBJ= new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray JS= JOBJ.getJSONArray("list");

    for (int i = 0; i < JS.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject c = JS.getJSONObject(i);

     JSONObject main= paramsArr.getJSONObject("main");
    System.out.println(main.getString("temp"));
        //like this...

    JSONArray JS2= JOBJ.getJSONArray("weather");
    for (int j = 0; j < JS2.length(); j++)
    {
     JSONObject param1 = JS2.getJSONObject(0);

    //now get required values by key
    System.out.println(param1.getInt("id"));
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you able to answer a query I have? What is "paramsArr"? Is it a user defined variable? String?